# Ruby on Rails App vs Core Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been doing some searching with ruby on rails but there is one thing I don't quite understand reading about it? What exactly is the difference between app and core development? Is core development improving upon rails while apps are for website creation? Any explanation on the difference would be useful. Thank you!

Comment: Rails Team is always want to see a new contributor like you. just carry on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. :)

If you're seeing "Rails Core" or "Rails Core Contributor" or the like, that's referring to development of Rails itself.

Rails apps are for app/site creation, as you stated.

(Though if you are in the app-building business, it is both useful and educational to pay attention to development of the framework itself.)

Answer (score 1):

You hit it right on the head there. Contributing to "rails core" means that you're adding on to the `rails` gem itself (https://github.com/rails/rails). Rails app development means that you've simply used rails to develop your own applications (e.g. `rails new myapp` and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Core development is for the development of rails itself, as stated above. I am looking to setup a Rails application development environment. I am looking for a vagrant box for a good virtual machine environment. I found [one here](https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box); however, it describes that the "VM is not designed for Rails application development, only Rails core development." This distinction is important to know.